# Python equivalent of any(isempty(x)) to test a list

Tags: python, matlab

I am writing my very first real Python program after years of MATLAB. The program reads in a comma delimited serial string from my Arduino GPS, converts the fields to numbers, plots them on a scatter graph, and then writes them to disk. Each line should look like this (with the precision degraded so no one shows up at my house):

```
2014, 12, 3, 16, 1, 56, 0, 46.3, -119.2, 118.3, 7
```

where the first 7 fields are the date and time, the next two are the coordinates, the next is the altitude, and the last is the number of satellites in view. If there is no lock, then I instead get something like this:

```
2014, 12, 3, 16, 1, 56, 0, , , , 0
```

I would like my program to see that there is no lock and skip that measurement. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
import serial
import string

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM27',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=5
)

while True:
    line = ser.readline()
    values = string.split(line, ',')

    validList = True
    for x in values:
        if not x:
            validList == False

    if not validList:
        continue

    for n in range(0, 6):
        values[n] = int(values[n])

    values[6] = float(values[6])
    values[7] = float(values[7])
```

However, the program will run for a while and then throw the following error:

```
values[n] = int(values[n])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Now in MATLAB, the list would be a cell and my test would be:

```
if any(isempty(values))
    continue;
end
```

How should I be validating my list?

Comment: Why not a `try except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check string in boolean context, empty string if `False`:

```
if not all(values): # h/t @chepner
    continue
```

But more pythonic is just to try to do what you want, and catch exception:

```
parts = line.split(',')
try:
    values = map(int, parts[:6]) + map(float, parts[6:])
    # you can check here, if you have enough items in values:
    assert len(values) > 7, "Too few values in this line"
except (ValueError, IndexError, AssertionError) as err:
    print err
    continue
```

In this case `ValueError` occurs when you cannot convert a string to 
desired format, and `IndexError` if there was less than 6 elements

You can use the same technique to unpack your values:

```
parts = line.split(',')
try:
    year, month, day, hour, minute, second = map(int, parts[:6])
    milisecond, lat, lon, alt, sat = map(float, parts[6:])
except (ValueError, IndexError) as err:
    print err
    continue
```

Comment: So the second technique is comparable to the MATLAB `deal` command? I can also see I have to learn more about `map`.

Comment: @craigim I don't remember much MATLAB, `map` just applies function provided as a first argument to items from they later args (they must be sequences). Probably more pythonic would be to use list comprehension, but I love `map` for its concise form. PS I improved the second version a bit.

Comment: I'm still getting used to 0 based indexing and have a further question: to access the first 6 elements of the list, you use `parts[:6]`, is that equivalent to `parts[0:5]`, or is it a typo?

Comment: the second number denotes a 'stop' element, so this is the first that goes not into the result sublist. So `lst[:6], lst[6:]` splits list in two parts, first having a six elements, second the rest. See http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html

Answer (score 1):

An empty value '' will evaluate as False.  You can evaluate the truth of all elements in the row:

```
if not all(map(lambda x: bool(x), values)):
    pass
```

Comment: `if not all(map(bool, values)):` is sufficient

Comment: `if not all(values)` is also sufficient. There's no need to explicitly convert the string to a Boolean value.

Comment: That's true.  My initial response was `map(lambda x: bool(x.strip()), l.split(","))`

in the event that there were spaces `' '` in the line.

Answer (score 1):

The check can be thinned up, but the problem with your current code is

```
for x in values:
    if not x:
        validList == False
```

`==` is the boolean equality operator, `=` is assignment. Also, since you keep comparing, you loose the interim values you check.

Change it to:

```
for x in values:
    if not x:
        validList = False
        break
```

You could also just check one of the fields you know to be empty when there isn't a lock:

```
if not values[7]:
    continue
```

Comment: Gah! Of course `==` is the wrong operator. To be fair, MATLAB's code checker would have flagged my sloppiness (not that that's an excuse).